# get list of events, including recurring ones, in a DVWP

Tags: data-view-web-part, recurring-events

I am trying to figure out how to configure my DVWP to get all events in a calendar that occur between two days, including recurring. I can't even figure out where to start. Everything I've ready is for SPServices but I want to use a DVWP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSOM and SOAP to get events from calendar including recurring event

Go through this method i have created to get all events from calendar.

```
function GetItemsFromCalendarAsmx () {
wsURL = webUrl + “_vti_bin/Lists.asmx”;
var xmlCall =  “<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=’http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&#8217;xmlns:xsd=’http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&#8217;xmlns:soap=’http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’&gt; <soap:Body>” +
      “<GetListItems xmlns=’http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/’>&#8221;+
      “<listName>” + calendarGuid + “</listName>” +
      “<query>” +
      “<Query>” +
      “<Where>” +
      “<DateRangesOverlap>” +
      “<FieldRef Name=\”EventDate\” />” +
      “<FieldRef Name=\”EndDate\” />” +
      “<FieldRef Name=\”RecurrenceID\” />” +
      “<Value Type=’DateTime’><Year/></Value>” +
      “</DateRangesOverlap>” +
      “</Where>” +
      “</Query>” +
      “</query>” +
      “<queryOptions>” +
      “<QueryOptions>” +
      “<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>” +
      “</QueryOptions>” +
      “</queryOptions>” +
      “</GetListItems>” +
      “</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>”;

var result = [];
$.ajax({
      url: wsURL,
      type: “POST”,
      dataType: “xml”,
      async: false,
      data: xmlCall,
      complete: function (xData, status) {
          Core.LogMessage(“Core.GetItemsFromCalendarAsmx-> url: ” + wsURL +     ” status: ” + status);
          if (status === “success”) {
               var root = $(xData.responseText);
               root.find(“listitems”).children().children().each(function ()                                
                $this = $(this);
                var ids = $this.attr(“ows_UniqueId”).split(“;”);
                var rec = $this.attr(“ows_fRecurrence”);
                    result.push({
                          “StartTime”: $this.attr(“ows_EventDate”),
                          “EndTime”: $this.attr(“ows_EndDate”),
                          “Title”: $this.attr(“ows_Title”),
                          “Recurrence”: (rec === “1” ? true : false),
                          “Description”: Core.HtmlDecode($this.attr(“ows_Description”)),
                          “Guid”: ids[1],
                          “Id”: ids[0],
                    });
               });
           }
         },
       contentType: “text/xml; charset=\”utf-8\””
       });
       return result;
    };
```

Comment: I need this in a DVWP so CSOM won't work.